# This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them. powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I tried to save a form from Excel, into an HTML file, then send the HTML file into email body but I got the error in the title.

```
$o = New-Object -com Outlook.Application
$mail = $o.CreateItem(0)
$mail.HTMLBody += Get-Content I:\SCRIPT\IPCNewScript\ResultFinal.html
$mail.cc = "abcd@imcnam.ssmb.com>"
$mail.To = "abcd@imcnam.ssmb.com>"

$mail.subject = "test"

$mail.save()`
```

[image: html file]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Instead of creating a COM object to Outlook (which is know for it's quirks and requires some in-depth knowledge of Powershell) you can use the native Send-Mailmessage command.

Answer (score 0):

So, you are getting this error in your Outlook client?
Then this is not a PoSH issue, but the Outlook client not being able to handle what you sent it.

Outlook,uses MSWord as it's rendering engine not IE. Thus MSWord has real issue with frames. I have seen MSWord many times we copying and pasting article content from the web either flat out fail, fail to render completely or balk at you to accept the formatting being passed or switch to the default.

Get-Content get the source of the file, and you are using that as your email body.

Depending on who yo send this to, you are assuming that are allow HTML in there mail client. This is often recommend against due to security risks, but this is not all folks of course. Even new version of Outlook block embedded HTML because of this risk as user must specifically click stuff to allow it to render.

Try sending this as an .html, .mht or .xls attachment or even a URL to a shared location/site vs embedding in the email body.